# how to get the inner node and its children value of xml document in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel

i have an xml document like the below

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
        <REQUESTDESC><REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME><STATICVARIABLES><SVCURRENTCOMPANY>MSIT</SVCURRENTCOMPANY></STATICVARIABLES></REQUESTDESC>
        <REQUESTDATA>
            <TALLYMESSAGE>
<Entry_x0020_NO.>125</Entry_x0020_NO.>
<DATE>12</DATE>
<GUID>1258</GUID>
<NARRATION>1542</NARRATION>
<VOTURETYPENAME>456</VOTURETYPENAME>
<NAME>achuth</NAME>
<AMOUNT>250</AMOUNT>
  </TALLYMESSAGE>
        </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

in which i need to get the inner node tally Message and its children inner text values using c# code in a loop and make each node as excel sheet column name and the values as row values in excel.
the error is below
[image: error is null reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this, solution uses `Linq` to `Xml`.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

    var messages = doc.Descendants("TALLYMESSAGE").Select(s=> new {
        Entry =  s.Element("Entry_x0020_NO.").Value,
        DATE =  s.Element("DATE").Value,
        GUID =  s.Element("GUID").Value,
        NARRATION =  s.Element("NARRATION").Value,
        VOTURETYPENAME =  s.Element("VOTURETYPENAME").Value,
        AMOUNT =  s.Element("AMOUNT").Value,
        NAME =  s.Element("NAME").Value,

    }).ToList();
```

**Update :**
As asked in comments, if you are looking to loop through each elements you could do this.

```
    foreach(var element in doc.Descendants("TALLYMESSAGE").Elements()) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", element.Name, element.Value);
    }
```

Check this [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lOMHCM)

Comment: can i save each as row of excel document?

Comment: That can be done, you have to write the logic to write to excel.

Comment: instead of for each i need to use the for loop to insert

Comment: can i use each as separately so that i can transfer each value

Comment: can u help me to create an excel sheet integration in which the child nodes of tally message are the column names and values are its rows?

Comment: I suggest post new Question.

Comment: It might mislead people reaching this post with similar problem, so always best to post specific question to each problem.

Comment: can u jest print to a message box instead of console

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} = {1}", element.Name, element.Value));`

Comment: how to get length of the children so that i can insert into excel using loop
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,i+1];

Comment: You cal use Elements.Count() to know number of elements